# Elegant way of turning Dictionary or Generator or Sequence in Swift into an Array?

Tags: swift

Is there an elegant way to convert Dictionary (or Sequence or Generator) into an Array. I know I can convert it by looping through the sequence as follows.

```
var d = ["foo" : 1, "bar" : 2]
var g: DictionaryGenerator<String, Int> = d.generate()

var a = Array<(String, Int)>()

while let item = g.next() {
    a += item
}
```

I am hoping there is something similar to Python's easy conversion:

```
>>> q = range(10)
>>> i = iter(q)
>>> i
<listiterator object at 0x1082b2090>
>>> z = list(i)
>>> z
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>>
```

Comment: Array(d.generate()) works I think.  I know there is a call on dictionary that can be used as an Array initializer to give you an array of tuples.

Comment: I have tried Array(d.generate()) and many other permutations. It definitely doesn't work. :-(

Comment: I'll do some digging in my old answers and get back to you.

Comment: Array(d) looks like it will give you an Array of tuples.

Answer (score 2):

The `+` operator for an array will accept a sequence, so you can write

```
var d = ["foo" : 1, "bar" : 2]
var a = [] + d
```

I don't think anything similar is possible for generators though

Comment: +1, I like it ... but David's solution feels little bit cleaner (less magic)

Answer (score 1):

Just pass it to the Array’s init:

```
var dict = ["foo" : 1, "bar" : 2]
var arr = Array(dict)
```